# Bus line 21 from Nice to Castellane

Tags: public-transport, france, buses, nice

It is my first time traveling to France, and I want to visit the beautiful Gorges du Verdon. I've booked a place at Castellane, and before going there, I'll be at Nice. I've done some research on how to get to Castellane, and it seems like the only way is to take bus line 21. However, I'm not sure where to take it from. It is stated that previously the bus leaves from the train station, but ever since the new tram routes were started, most buses shifted their location of departure. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

According to both the [bus schedule](http://www.info-ler.fr/fr/lignes-horaires/carte-et-fiches-horaires-n287) for [line 21](http://www.info-ler.fr/core/file.get?path=//doc/ficheshoraires/20132014/bat2014/fh21.pdf) on the [regional bus authority (LER)](http://www.info-ler.fr/)'s website, and to the [Castellane tourism office website](http://www.castellane.org/fr/aller-en-bus-car-autocar-autobus-a-castellane-gorges-du-verdon.aspx), the bus leaves from the *gare routière* (bus station).

There is an [information desk](http://www.phoceens-cars.com/vous-informer-c1-p6.html) on Avenue des Diables Bleus (gare routière de Saint-Jean d'Angély) [[Google Maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Avenue+des+Diables+Bleus,+06300+Nice/@43.7052193,7.2839779,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x12cddaca41392371:0xcd88edc8128d2c8e)]. This is also the address given by [LER](http://www.info-ler.fr/fr/titres-tarifs/gares-routieres-en-provence-alpes-cote-d-azur-n267). It is located near the Nice-Riquier train station, not close to the main train station.

The [historic building](http://www.emporis.com/building/gare-routiere-de-nice-nice-france) was demolished in 2011 and the bus stops were [spread out over several sites](http://www.nicematin.com/article/societe/gare-routiere-ou-prendrez-vous-le-bus-ce-mercredi.406199.html), so don't set any store to information older than 2011. I can't find any more recent news in the local paper. Do note that some [local buses around this sector](http://www.lignesdazur.com/perturbation/index.asp?rub_code=17&pert_id=9173&laction=preview) are being deviated.

Beware that I'm not a local, I'm only reporting what information I could find on the web (in French). If nobody can come up with better information, you may want to scout out the day before or ask at a local tourist information desk. And please report your findings here!

There is only one bus at 7 in the morning, and another bus at 14:40 except Sundays and holidays (this region is not friendly to travelers without a car). Don't miss it!

Comment: +1 Last year we hired a car in Nice for 24 hours, drove to Castellane, saw the Gorges du Verdon early in the morning, and drove back to Nice before lunchtime the next day. Definitely worth it, would have been quite a different experience on a bus (we stopped in some little tiny mountain villages that a bus wouldn't have come near).

Answer (score 1):

I know for sure that the bus stops at Nice airport which is where I took it from.